# AddThis "Like/share"window cuts off when pressed in a Tumblr theme. Easy fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, addthis

The Tumblr theme I am using doesn't have built-in like/share features, so i decided to use the AddThis widget to place share buttons on each post.

The widget is inserted just fine into the html, but if I click the "like" button, the share window gets cut off and I am unable to post onto facebook.

Is there an easy way to remedy this with css, or will I need something more complex?

Here is the site to let you see what I mean: [blog.hinge.co](http://blog.hinge.co)

Comment: Just tried out the FB Like button and was able to click and share to my wall.  I tried in Chrome, can you confirm it still isn't working and specify the browser/OS combination you're using.

Comment: Looks to be working for me, too.